# How can I find a question I know I asked, but can't remember what site I asked it on?

Tags: support, questions

I distinctly remember asking a question somewhere where I asked for an example of an algorithm with a specific O(n) complexity, but I can't remember where I asked it. I checked the most likely culprits (statistics, mathematics, computer science), but they don't appear to be on those. It might have been deleted, but I don't know. Is there a way for me to find this question again?

Comment: _" It might have been deleted ..."_ Under 10k rep you can see deleted questions only from the last 60 days.

Comment: @user289905 what if the title of the question is open, but the question body much more specific, how would the OP find that question in a list of hundreds?

Comment: Use Google @Mari-LouA

Comment: @Luuklag then you'd agree that the answer on the older question is not perhaps the most suitable for this OP. Moreover, neither solution would unearth a deleted post.